# dig/nslookup can't connect but ping can

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager, 17.04, dns

I just updated to 17.04; it broke my VPN app.  As I was testing things, I found dig and nslookup weren't able to connect:

```
<me@mycomp>:~$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
<me@mycomp>:~$ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

However, ping does

```
<me@mycomp>:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.9.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga34s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.9.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=21.8 ms
64 bytes from lga34s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.9.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=21.9 ms
64 bytes from lga34s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.9.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=21.8 ms
64 bytes from lga34s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.9.238): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=21.9 ms
64 bytes from lga34s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.9.238): icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=21.9 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.850/21.903/21.940/0.190 ms
```

Here is my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search mit.edu
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

My understanding is the last line is set by dnsmasq, but that isn't in my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Any idea what's going on/how I can fix dig and nslookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: added dns=dnsmasq to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`